# grpc failed error using geocoder getFromLocationName method

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error while try to get location of a address.

here's the stack trace:

```
W: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
W:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
W:     at ir.aaraddarman.maptest.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:514)
```

I try everything and i exhausted.
i just don't know why it's not working somebody please help me or show me another way to achieve my purpose

this is my main class:

```
  public static void getLocationFromAddress(final String address, final Context context, final Handler handler) {
    Log.i("shot", "getLocationFromAddress");
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.i("shot", "thread run");
        LatLng latLng = null;
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        if (geocoder.isPresent()){
          Log.i("shot", "isPresent ");
        }
        try {
          Log.i("shot", "try ");
          List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5);
          Log.i("shot", "list: " + list);
          if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            // sending back first address line and locality
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.i("shot", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder" + e);
        } finally {
          Message msg = Message.obtain();
          msg.setTarget(handler);
          if (latLng != null) {
            msg.what = 1;
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("address", "" + latLng);
            msg.setData(bundle);
          } else
            msg.what = 0;
          msg.sendToTarget();
        }
      }
    };
    thread.start();
  }
```

and this is my handler class:

```
  private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
      String result;
      switch (message.what) {
        case 1:
          Bundle bundle = message.getData();
          result = bundle.getString("address");
          break;
        default:
          result = null;
      }
      // replace by what you need to do
      Log.i("shot", "result: " + result);
    }
  }
```

Comment: "I keep getting this error while try to get location of a address" -- please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace for your error.

Comment: My guess is that your app cannot contact the Google server that supplies the geocoding responses.